# Bash Script unable to run Java Program as cron job

Tags: java, linux, bash, cron, ubuntu-14.04

I am trying to run a .class file from a bash script every 1 minute using the crontab. I get the error Could not find or load main class Cron_Read_Send_CapacityData_To_Graphite. I have already set environment variable on my machine.

If i run the bash script from the terminal it works fine.Note the bash script and the java class file are in the same folder

Script:

```
$ cat Run_Cron_Read_Send_CapacityData_To_Graphite.sh
#!/bin/bash

java Cron_Read_Send_CapacityData_To_Graphite >> /home/marshell/graphite_cronjobs/Cron_Read_Send_CapacityData_To_Graphite.log
```

Cron entry:

```
$ crontab -e

*/1 * * * * /home/marshell/graphite_cronjobs/Run_Cron_Read_Send_CapacityData_To_Graphite.sh >> /home/marshell/graphite_cronjobs/debug_cronjob.log 2>&1
```

Error:

```
Error: Could not find or load main class Cron_Read_Send_CapacityData_To_Graphite
```

Comment: Environment variables you set in your shell init files (or in your interactive shell) may not be in effect for a shell run from cron (depending on how you set it). Try setting class path/etc. in the script explicitly.

Comment: Hi i set it in /etc/environment this is the line i added  JAVA_HOME="/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java"

Comment: Does it work if you run the script without cron?

Comment: I believe `/etc/environment` is a pam thing and cron is likely not dealing with that either.

Comment: Yes it works if i don't use cron job. I tried running the .sh file from terminal it works fine

Comment: `JAVA_HOME` and the `CLASSPATH` are two different variables, see for example this [external link](http://www.coderanch.com/t/600047/java/java/Difference-JAVA-HOME-JRE-HOME). The error message indicates a classpath problem. Try setting CLASSPATH too, see this [Oracle documentation page](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/classpath.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You error message indicates that your classpath isn't set correctly for the script to find `Cron_Read_Send_CapacityData_To_Graphite.class`, I would use something like -

```
CP=/home/marshell/graphite_cronjobs # The classpath to use
LF=$CP/Cron_Read_Send_CapacityData_To_Graphite.log # the log file
java -cp $CP Cron_Read_Send_CapacityData_To_Graphite >> $LF
```

Comment: will this crontab entry start on system reboot ?