# schedule a job in unix by crontab

Tags: java, shell, unix, ubuntu, cron

I have created a simple java program for printing "Hello world". code is as follows

```
public class Hello {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.out.println("Hello world!");
    }

}
```

Class has been compiled already and it is in the same directory.
In same directory I have created a shell file named temp.sh which contains command

```
java Hello
```

now if I execute this shell file then java program is being executed successfully.
I have written a cronjob to execute it every minute

```
* * * * * /home/ashutosh/Documents/javaPractice/temp.sh >> /var/log/myjob.log 2>&1
```

now in my logs it is showing

```
could not load main class java
```

i don't know what is the problem. I have tried by giving absolute path of the java file but nothing helped. Help me.

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Bash Script unable to run Java Program as cron job](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25894558/bash-script-unable-to-run-java-program-as-cron-job)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that the working directory of the cronjob is not the directory where your class resides. So add a `cd the_right_directory` into the script or change the classpath of java with something like `java -cp some_directory Hello`

Answer (score 1):

Inside temp.sh try using full path:

```
java /home/ashutosh/Documents/javaPractice/Hello
```

Answer (score 0):

use  `java -cp ./ Hello` to run the program. `-cp ./` add the current directory to the classpath.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look here for [cron-tab examples](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2009/06/15-practical-crontab-examples/) and take a look of this example [Bash Script unable to run Java Program as cron job](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25894558/bash-script-unable-to-run-java-program-as-cron-job)

Answer (score 0):

You should set environment variables in your script file, something like CLASSPATH. Or just source .profile first before you run script. Refer to https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/27289/how-can-i-run-a-cron-command-with-existing-environmental-variables.